# RHEL6 NO Longer Supported by Google Chrome, Is there a way around it?

Tags: google-chrome, rhel-6

I'm getting an error while trying to update my Google Chrome in RHEL6.

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo yum update
[sudo] password for alexus: 
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-beta.x86_64 0:27.0.1453.93-200836 will be updated
---> Package google-chrome-beta.x86_64 0:28.0.1500.20-201172 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: google-chrome-beta-28.0.1500.20-201172.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: google-chrome-beta-28.0.1500.20-201172.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ uname -a
Linux wcmisdlin02.uftmasterad.org 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 16 11:21:38 CDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

I found following article(s):

- [Google Says Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Is Obsolete [Updated] | Muktware](http://www.muktware.com/5203/google-says-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-obsolete)
- [RHEL 6 Is Not Obsolete: Google Chrome | Muktware](http://www.muktware.com/5211/rhel-6-no-more-obsolete-according-google)

Is there anything can be done to move to v28 on RHEL6? (other then wait for RHEL7)?

Comment: I assumed you tried `--skip-broken`? I should add that Chrome stop supporting FHEL6 since **`Release 27`**  In the end the likely hood is that Google has migrated their standard library and you are simply out of luck.

Comment: no point of trying `--skip-broken` as it will skip the only one package "google-chrome-beta". I'm sure what I'm saying is (nearly) impossible but who knows, maybe someone will find a way to get it going somehow)

Comment: Perhaps you could switch to [Chromium](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) and compile from source?  Not ideal, I understand, but essentially the same browser and would get you there.

Comment: @alexus - I am not familar with the command was trying to suggest the least path of resistance.  Anyways Google has migrated from the old standard library so there isn't much you can unless your able to replace the std library used by RHEL6 yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also try the script here:

[How to install 64-bit Google Chrome 28+ on 64-bit RHEL/CentOS 6 or 7](http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/)

It downloads/installs the latest Chrome plus various libraries extracted from downloaded Fedora 15 RPMs. It's allowed me to run Chrome 28 on my 64-bit CentOS 6.4 system successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing an old version as described in this post: http://georgeinenglish.com/solved-google-chrome-no-longer-installs-on-centos-6-4/

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is that it is a gcc version issue/requirement upcoming versions of chrome is setting. you can try upgrading gcc to version 4.7.0. I personally haven't tried it since my rhel6 machine is locked at the version it has do to project requirements, but if you get it working I'd like to know so that I can update once I finish this current project.