# This computer will soon stop receiving Google Chrome updates because this Linux system will no longer be supported

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I'm using `Google Chrome - Version 48.0.2564.41 unknown (64-bit)` on following system:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) 
$
```

and I got following message:

> This computer will soon stop receiving Google Chrome updates because
>   this Linux system will no longer be supported.

A while back I asked similar question:

[linux - RHEL6 NO Longer Supported by Google Chrome, Is there a way around it? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/601326/rhel6-no-longer-supported-by-google-chrome-is-there-a-way-around-it)

This time it is `RHEL7` that's reporting that message(

Help?

*** UPDATE ***

I updated my system to newer version of CentOS 7.2:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
$
```

message still appears(

Answer (score 3):

This is because Google doesn't claim to support RHEL or CentOS.  [Their documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?hl=en) only says it supports "Ubuntu 12.04+, Debian 7+, OpenSuSE 13.1+, or Fedora Linux 21" which is laughable because Fedora 21 isn't even supported by Fedora anymore, only Fedora 22 and 23.

In the past, the support was removed because of some base libraries that Chrome relied on being too old, but considering how many internal libraries are bundled into the RPM, I find that hard to believe.  Most likely, the people who package RPMs for google are not interested in RPM-based distros and make a half-hearted effort to package Chrome.  This is most likely why Red Hat packages their own Chromium packages.  Hopefully that eventually is something CentOS can use too.

Comment: There is an open issue for chromium to support centos7.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=581297

Comment: Update: Chromium fixed this a couple months ago. They lowered the requirements so RHEL/CentOS 7 is able to run chrome.